# pdfbox, cpu 100% while extracting text

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using pdfbox 2.0.1 to parse pdf document like this.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);
                    PDDocument document = null;
                    PDFTextStripper stripper;
                    String content;

                    try {
                        document = PDDocument.load(in);

                        stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                        content = stripper.getText(document).trim();
                    } finally {
                        if (document != null) {
                            document.close();
                        }
                        if (in != null) {
                            in.close();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(content);
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

Sometimes it happened that cpu runs 100% while parsing pdf concurrently. The stack is as follow:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:303)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.encoding.GlyphList.toUnicode(GlyphList.java:231)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.toUnicode(PDSimpleFont.java:308)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.toUnicode(PDSimpleFont.java:273)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.showText(PDFStreamEngine.java:668)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.showTextStrings(PDFStreamEngine.java:609)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.ShowTextAdjusted.process(ShowTextAdjusted.java:52)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:815)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:472)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:446)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:149)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStreamEngine.processPage(PDFTextStreamEngine.java:136)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:391)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:319)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:266)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:227)
```

GlyphList.java code is:

```
// Adobe Glyph List (AGL)
private static final GlyphList DEFAULT = load("glyphlist.txt", 4281);


 /**
     * Returns the Unicode character sequence for the given glyph name, or null if there isn't any.
     *
     * @param name PostScript glyph name
     * @return Unicode character(s), or null.
     */
public String toUnicode(String name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    String unicode = nameToUnicode.get(name);
    if (unicode != null)
    {
        return unicode;
    }

    // separate read/write cache for thread safety
    unicode = uniNameToUnicodeCache.get(name);
    if (unicode == null)
    {
        // test if we have a suffix and if so remove it
        if (name.indexOf('.') > 0)
        {
            unicode = toUnicode(name.substring(0, name.indexOf('.')));
        }
        else if (name.startsWith("uni") && name.length() == 7)
        {
            // test for Unicode name in the format uniXXXX where X is hex
            int nameLength = name.length();
            StringBuilder uniStr = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                for (int chPos = 3; chPos + 4 <= nameLength; chPos += 4)
                {
                    int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(chPos, chPos + 4), 16);
                    if (codePoint > 0xD7FF && codePoint < 0xE000)
                    {
                        LOG.warn("Unicode character name with disallowed code area: " + name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        uniStr.append((char) codePoint);
                    }
                }
                unicode = uniStr.toString();
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                LOG.warn("Not a number in Unicode character name: " + name);
            }
        }
        else if (name.startsWith("u") && name.length() == 5)
        {
            // test for an alternate Unicode name representation uXXXX
            try
            {
                int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(1), 16);
                if (codePoint > 0xD7FF && codePoint < 0xE000)
                {
                    LOG.warn("Unicode character name with disallowed code area: " + name);
                }
                else
                {
                    unicode = String.valueOf((char) codePoint);
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                LOG.warn("Not a number in Unicode character name: " + name);
            }
        }
        uniNameToUnicodeCache.put(name, unicode);
    }
    return unicode;
}
```

so， when we call like this

```
GlyphList.DEFAULT.toUnicode(code)
```

the concurrent error occurs(pay attention to var uniNameToUnicodeCache), and PDSimpleFont.toUnicode just did that.

However, it seems that no other ones have met the same problem。i don't know what i said above is right, or wrong. And if it's really a bug, is it fixed?

Comment: Why not retry with the current version? 2.0.9

Comment: if what i see is right, i think 2.0.9 still exists this problem, becuase the codes keep the same.

Comment: *"the concurrent error occurs"* - which concurrent error? Your question only mentions a 100% cpu which by itself does not imply some concurrency error. Furthermore, you don't indicate how you concurrently execute code, the code you show is single threaded only. Please indicate how to reproduce the issue. Then you mention you call  `GlyphList.DEFAULT.toUnicode(code)` but I don't see that code in the code you provide saying you *parse pdf document like this*.

Comment: And your title is wrong, you're not parsing, you're extracting text.

Comment: Even if the code of `public String toUnicode(String name)` hasn't changed (which I didn't investigate), other things have changed. Many things were done to optimize speed and memory usage.

Comment: That been said, reviewing the code one sees that the `GlyphList` class is not at all prepared for multi-threaded use. On the other hand it is used via singletons, so multi-threaded text extraction will eventually use the `GlyphList` singletons concurrently. And `toUnicode` indeed not only reads from `uniNameToUnicodeCache` but also writes to it. Here some explicit synchronization or usage of a `concurrent Map`  class would make sense.

Comment: I'd propose trying to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` for `uniNameToUnicodeCache`.

Comment: i've changed my title... and i show my concurrent call, but notice that 5 times' call won't bring errors, the error occurs after a very long time running in my company's machine.

Comment: If you have a log of such an error with stack trace at your hand, please post it.

Comment: to Tilman Hausherr, look at my error stack, just from[PDSimpleFont.java:273], you'll find it's equivalent to code [GlyphList.DEFAULT.toUnicode(code)]

Comment: to mkl, all errors are same, just like this. i want to use concurrenthashmap rather than hashmap, but it's not my code, it's a jar. it's pom is<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: PDFBox is open source. Thus, you can simply edit it and compile a replacement. Use different Maven coordinates for it, though. Alternatively try and use reflection to inject a different `uniNameToUnicodeCache` instance. This may break with updates, though.

Comment: If this is a background task you can reduce the thread priority that **may** reduce the cpu usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing the `GlyphList` class code it becomes apparent that it has not been prepared for multi-threaded use. On the other hand a `DEFAULT` instance of it is used as a singleton via `getAdobeGlyphList` concurrently by text extraction code.

This can become an issue in its `toUnicode(String)` method if the documents in question use glyph names using the inofficial scheme `uniXXXX` or `uXXXX` because in such a case this method not only tries to read from the `HashMap uniNameToUnicodeCache` but also writes to it (adding the found inofficial glyph name for later quick lookup).

If such a write happens concurrently with some other thread's read from the map, indeed a `ConcurrentModificationException` may occur.

I'd propose changing the `GlyphList` to either

- not write to `uniNameToUnicodeCache` anymore, or
- synchronize `toUnicode(String)` or more precisely the `uniNameToUnicodeCache` reads and writes therein, or
- make `uniNameToUnicodeCache` a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

I would expect the third option to perform better than the second one.

Comment: Yes, I agree that, but this is a common pdf extract tool, and i can't modify it's code. maybe the thing i can only do is using it in single thread?

Comment: I see, and i think i should inform the pdfbox to fix the bug.

Comment: @mkl thanks, yes, 3 is better because it wouldn't be used after some time. I wonder why this problem has never occured before, we do have a mass test that works in parallel.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, open an issue plz...my english is poor...so i think it's better for you to do this...and plz inform me this issue after u creating it.. thank u

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4181 I'll ping you again when the build is done. The build server is quite slow currently.

Comment: @Tilman *"I wonder why this problem has never occured before"*  - do your mass tests use documents with `uXXXX` or `uniXXXX` glyph names? Because only for them we have a critical path.

Comment: @mkl I haven't analyzed the files for that, so one can only guess that our tests don't have many of them and villa has many of them.

Comment: @villa snapshot here: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.10-SNAPSHOT/